# XSL using a string as a variable name

Tags: xslt

I am writing a function that takes a parameter.  I would like to use that parameter (which should be a string) to construct a variable name.  As an example:

```
<xsl:function name="getVarWithName">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:variable name="return"><xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$var$name"><xsl:value-of select="$var$name" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Does Not Exist</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose></xsl:variable>
</xsl:function>
```

I would hope that calling the above function with the parameter `sample` would attempt to access the variable `varsample`.

Is this possible in XSL, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Now tell us what problem you are trying to solve, and perhaps we can help you.

Comment: @MichaelKay There are several instances in our code where we check for a variable, and if it doesn't contain anything, fall back to another similarly named variable.  I was looking to make a function that would remove the duplicated code.

Comment: So, you're tired of writing `<xsl:choose>` blocks?  Welcome to the club.  I suspect many of us have a function in our personal toolkits similar to the one I've written, called `value-or-default(arg1, arg2)`, that has some set of rules to determine if arg1 is a valid value, and returns arg1 if so, and if not, returns arg2.

Comment: My usual coding pattern for that is `select="($var, $default)[1]"`.

Comment: @bjimba actually, when I said "similarly named", I meant it.  It would either be `variableName` or `prefix:variableName` with the same prefix every time.